# QGIS "transform error" after downloading from OpenStreetMap

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, coordinate-system, wgs84

Beginner's question. I am working on this tutorial:
http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/basic_analysis.html

After selecting WGS84 UTM zone 34S in Project Properties, I receive several of these transform error messages:

Simplify transform error caught: forward transform of
(0.366535, 1.570812)
PROJ.4: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +to +proj=utm +zone=34 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

Can anyone guide me as to next steps? From other questions I've read on this site I assume it's a long/lat issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The coordinates 0.3665 1.5708 seem to be in the northern hemisphere, so UTM 34S is not an appropriate CRS.

UTM 31N would fit better.

The point falls into the Atlantic Ocean. I doubt that this is correct. Are you sure you have changed the **project** CRS, and not the **layer** CRS?